# Google client API - limit oauth authentication to my domain

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api-client

Has anyone had any experience of using the `Google Client API` to authorise against their domain by restricting the domain a user can login with?

The titbit that is required appears to be a qs parameter: `hd='[Domain name]'`

but there's nothing similar in the `OAuth2Parameters` parameters object

```
var oap = new OAuth2Parameters
{
        AccessToken = Current == null ? null : Current.AccessToken,
        RefreshToken = Current == null ? null : Current.RefreshToken,
        ClientId = GoogleClientId,
        ClientSecret = GoogleClientSecret,
        Scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme.Concatenate("://", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority,                                                                             "/Builder/Authentication/Receive"),
        AccessType = "offline" //ensures a refresh token (tho not currently working),
        *HD = //Hmm if only... :(((*

    };
var authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(oap);

return Redirect(authorizationUrl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so,in fact, all we need is to adjust the url thus:

```
var authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(oap);
authorizationUrl += "&hd=" + "mydomain.com".UrlEncode();
return Redirect(authorizationUrl);
```

Hope that helps someone down the line.

Comment: Can't users just modify the redirect url, and add their own domain?

Answer (score 0):

Use **hd** parameter.

[Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#GetAuth)

**Warning:** This tag is documented in **OAuth 1.0 API Reference**. In version 2 is not documented but works.

> Important: OAuth 1.0 has been officially deprecated as of April 20,
>   2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible.